# Convert Conv2Dtranspose into Upsample and conv in generator layer Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network, dcgan

I'm working with GANs and I was getting artifacts and the best way to remove them is to change the generator blocks conv2dtranspose into an upsample and a convolution as suggested by many papers.
I'm trying to generate ASL hand symbols via my personal dataset
[image: Generated Images]
[image]

this is the block code that implies conv2dtranspose as mentioned in the screenshot above

```py
def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, bias=False,
            ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
```

What I'm trying to achieve is change the block so that it up samples the image and applies convolution to it producing the same output image size as the conv2dTranspose

this is what i tried

```py
nn.Upsample(scale_factor = 2, mode='bilinear'),
            nn.ReflectionPad2d(1),
            nn.Conv2d(out_channels, int(out_channels / 2),kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
```

However I was getting the following error
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4fa61054bc2c> in <module>
     81         for _ in range(CRITIC_ITERATIONS):
     82             noise = torch.randn(cur_batch_size, Z_DIM, 1, 1).to(device)
---> 83             fake = gen(noise,labels)
     84             critic_real = critic(real,labels).reshape(-1)
     85             critic_fake = critic(fake,labels).reshape(-1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-10-6af8005acf1f> in forward(self, x, labels)
     77         embedding=self.embed(labels).unsqueeze(2).unsqueeze(3)
     78         x=torch.cat([x,embedding],dim=1)
---> 79         return self.net(x)
     80 
     81 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py in forward(self, input)
    115     def forward(self, input):
    116         for module in self:
--> 117             input = module(input)
    118         return input
    119 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py in forward(self, input)
    115     def forward(self, input):
    116         for module in self:
--> 117             input = module(input)
    118         return input
    119 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py in forward(self, input)
    421 
    422     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 423         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight)
    424 
    425 class Conv3d(_ConvNd):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight)
    418                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    419         return F.conv2d(input, weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 420                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    421 
    422     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [1024, 2048, 1, 1], expected input[64, 200, 2, 2] to have 2048 channels, but got 200 channels instead
```

Also if I change the stride to 1 it gives me embedding errors

```
=================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Param #
=================================================================
├─Sequential: 1-1                        --
|    └─Sequential: 2-1                   --
|    |    └─Upsample: 3-1                --
|    |    └─Conv2d: 3-2                  411,648
|    |    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-3             4,096
|    |    └─LeakyReLU: 3-4               --
|    └─Sequential: 2-2                   --
|    |    └─Upsample: 3-5                --
|    |    └─Conv2d: 3-6                  2,098,176
|    |    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-7             2,048
|    |    └─LeakyReLU: 3-8               --
|    └─Sequential: 2-3                   --
|    |    └─Upsample: 3-9                --
|    |    └─Conv2d: 3-10                 524,800
|    |    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-11            1,024
|    |    └─LeakyReLU: 3-12              --
|    └─Sequential: 2-4                   --
|    |    └─Upsample: 3-13               --
|    |    └─Conv2d: 3-14                 131,328
|    |    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-15            512
|    |    └─LeakyReLU: 3-16              --
|    └─Sequential: 2-5                   --
|    |    └─Upsample: 3-17               --
|    |    └─Conv2d: 3-18                 32,896
|    |    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-19            256
|    |    └─LeakyReLU: 3-20              --
|    └─ConvTranspose2d: 2-6              6,147
|    └─Tanh: 2-7                         --
├─Embedding: 1-2                         2,700
=================================================================
Total params: 3,215,631
Trainable params: 3,215,631
Non-trainable params: 0
=================================================================
=================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Param #
=================================================================
├─Sequential: 1-1                        --
|    └─Conv2d: 2-1                       2,080
|    └─LeakyReLU: 2-2                    --
|    └─Sequential: 2-3                   --
|    |    └─Conv2d: 3-1                  32,768
|    |    └─InstanceNorm2d: 3-2          128
|    |    └─LeakyReLU: 3-3               --
|    └─Sequential: 2-4                   --
|    |    └─Conv2d: 3-4                  131,072
|    |    └─InstanceNorm2d: 3-5          256
|    |    └─LeakyReLU: 3-6               --
|    └─Sequential: 2-5                   --
|    |    └─Conv2d: 3-7                  524,288
|    |    └─InstanceNorm2d: 3-8          512
|    |    └─LeakyReLU: 3-9               --
|    └─Sequential: 2-6                   --
|    |    └─Conv2d: 3-10                 2,097,152
|    |    └─InstanceNorm2d: 3-11         1,024
|    |    └─LeakyReLU: 3-12              --
|    └─Conv2d: 2-7                       8,193
├─Embedding: 1-2                         442,368
=================================================================
Total params: 3,239,841
Trainable params: 3,239,841
Non-trainable params: 0
=================================================================
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4fa61054bc2c> in <module>
     83             fake = gen(noise,labels)
     84             critic_real = critic(real,labels).reshape(-1)
---> 85             critic_fake = critic(fake,labels).reshape(-1)
     86             gp = gradient_penalty(critic,labels, real, fake, device=device)
     87             loss_critic = (

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-1-4154f5f318f2> in forward(self, x, labels)
     38     def forward(self, x,labels):
     39         embedding=self.embed(labels).view(labels.shape[0],1,self.img_size,self.img_size)
---> 40         x=torch.cat([x,embedding],dim=1)
     41         return self.disc(x)
     42 

RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Got 128 and 64 (The offending index is 0)
```

Could someone explain how would I achieve this for my architecture.